# Permissions issue

Tags: permissions

I have had to add two users to site.  One user can see the drop down menu and access the site but the other cannot.  Both users are in the same permission group created within SharePoint.  The menu has audiences assigned to them however the permission group is listed in the audience.  Any ideas what could be stopping the user from seeing the menu?

Comment: Update: The user can access the site directly via the URL

Comment: try to compile the audience group from central admin...